# focus visible input by using jquery focus event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('body', function () {
        var visibleInput = $("input[type=text]").filter(':visible');
        visibleInput.focus();
    });
});
```

it doesn't work this way I wonder why. No error in the console.

Comment: your code is working withour $(document).on('body',function()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type=text]").filter(':visible').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there no body events in either JQuery or javascript. Normally you can't focus multiple elements at a time so use second one else it will focus on last textinput only.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var visibleInput = $("input[type=text]").filter(':visible');
        visibleInput.focus();       //Focus last textinput with visible not first one. 

});
```

If you want focus first textinput with visible try this one

```
$("input[type=text]").filter(':visible').first().focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

How many inputs are there on the page?

Only one input can have focus at a time... I would assume that that variable declaration would  pick up each input.